# How to enhance the select2 multi select bar?

Tags: woocommerce, jquery-select2, multi-select

```
 <select id="multiple_select_company" name = "multi_dropdown[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px">


 jQuery('#multiple_select_company').select2({theme: "classic", placeholder: "Select a Company"});
```

I am facing a problem when I use a multi select bar, the bar does not appear and options cluster above the select bar. I have posted the select statement and the select2 call. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please post the code what have you done so far ?

Comment: I have posted the select statement and the call to select2